# Model configuration error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am uploading excel file to my code based Entity framework object. I am getting error  !['System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException' occurred
in EnttiyFramework.dllbut wasnothand1ed inuser code
]: https://i.imgur.com/K6jJ0tX.png .
Can anyone give me idea how to resolve it
Below is my code for class file

```
 public class dataextract
 {
 public string Code { get; set; }
 public string Name1 { get; set; }
 public string Group1 { get; set; }
}
```

In datacontext

```
public class ReadContext : DbContext
{
    public ReadContext()
       : base("name = ExcelConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new 
          MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ReadContext,      
                 ReadAndDisplayExcel.Migrations.Configuration>());
    }
    public DbSet<dataextract> dataext { get; set; }

}
```

In Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
    {
        //List<dataextract> lstStudent = new List<dataextract>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (uploadfile != null && uploadfile.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                //ExcelDataReader works on binary excel file
                Stream stream = uploadfile.InputStream;
                //We need to written the Interface.
                IExcelDataReader reader = null;
                if (uploadfile.FileName.EndsWith(".xls"))
                {
                    //reads the excel file with .xls extension
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
                }
                else if (uploadfile.FileName.EndsWith(".xlsx"))
                {
                    //reads excel file with .xlsx extension
                    reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Shows error if uploaded file is not Excel file
                    ModelState.AddModelError("File", "This file format is not supported");
                    return View();
                }               


                var conf = new ExcelDataSetConfiguration
                {
                    ConfigureDataTable = _ => new ExcelDataTableConfiguration
                    {
                        UseHeaderRow = true
                    }
                };

                DataSet result = reader.AsDataSet(conf);
                DataTable s1 = result.Tables[0];

                reader.Close();                  


                 using (ReadContext db = new ReadContext())
                 {var query = from s in s1.AsEnumerable()

                                select new
                                {

                                    CODE = s.Field<Double>("CODE").ToString(),
                                    Name = s.Field<string>("Name").ToString(),
                                    Group = s.Field<string>("Group").ToString()
                                };
                    var q1 = query.Select(x => new dataextract
                    {

                        CODE = x.CODE,
                        Name = x.Name,
                        Group = x.Group,
                    }).ToList();

                    foreach (var ss in q1)
                     {

                          db.dataext.Add(ss);//error happening at this line 
                     }
                     db.SaveChanges();

                 }

                return View(s1);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("File","Please upload your file");
        }
        return View();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your entity model primary key field is not there either create new field

```
public class dataextract
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
   [Key]
   public int dataextractId { get; set; }
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Name1 { get; set; }
   public string Group1 { get; set; }
}
```

or choose code field as your entity filed

```
public class dataextract
{ 
   [Key]
   public string Code { get; set; }
   public string Name1 { get; set; }
   public string Group1 { get; set; }
}
```